# What is difference between monolithic, microkernel and exokernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, microkernel

Could anyone please explain, what are the differences between  monolithic, microkernel and exokernel ?

Comment: Currently written question contains no research part. While self-answered questions are allowed on SO, they should obey standard rules.

Comment: So, thanks Yogesh for self answering the question you made.

Answer (score 4):

There are many differences between these kernel types. They differ in implementing kernel services like memory management, process management etc.

Monolithic kernel implements all kernel services so its bigger in size where as exokernel implements nothing in kernel part so it is much lighter and microkernel sits in between mono and exo kernel.

On the other hand, in case of exokernel everything is implemented in nonkernel part so application developer has to decide what to do with allocated resources. There will be no such overhead in case of monolithic kernel.

To know more differences following link may be usefull for you.
( https://gettech1.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/difference-between-monolithic-microkernel-and-exokernel/ )

Comment: This is actually a link-only answer: all information aside link(`They differ in implementing kernel services like.. `) is too broad. Link-only answers are discouraged on SO. And this particular answer smells like promotion of your own blog.

Comment: OMG...My intention was not to promote my blog. I just thought to share this information with all. And if it smells, I will remove it.

Comment: It is not bad to get link to resource (owned by you or not), but the answer post itself should contain some information. E.g., you may qoute first 2 lines from the table in your blog. See also [how-to-answer tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) (paragraph "Provide context for links").

Comment: @ Tsyvarev, I have edited my answer as per the link provided by you.

Comment: The answer is much better now. (As for text formatting, preferrable way is to begin *new paragraph* by double new-line symbols instead of using some amount of spaces to *visually begin new line*.)